# How do I turn off syntax highlighting on Windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, colors, windows-10

I"m using Windows PowerShell on Windows 10.  Although I have been able to adjust background and most foreground colors,

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how to turn off syntax highlighting or change the colors

[image]

Where is this setting located?

Answer (score 3):

The dynamic syntax highlighting comes from the [`PSReadLine` module](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine) that ships with PowerShell in Windows 10.

You can "reset" all the token colors to whatever the console host application uses:

```
# Prepare a dictionary to hold all the new token-color mappings
$colorMap = @{}

# Fetch the possible coloring options
Get-PSReadLineOption |Get-Member *Color -MemberType Property |ForEach-Object {
    # Add a mapping to our dictionary that overrides the existing setting with whatever foreground color is used by the console
    $colorMap[$_.Name -replace 'Color$'] = [Console]::ForegroundColor
}

# Use the dictionary to update the highlighting settings
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors $colorMap
```